# How to return data from a database for a logged-in user in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

**Scenario:**

I have two APIs currently. A RegisterAPI and a LoginAPI. The RegisterAPI registers a new user and a LoginAPI allows them to access **their details only**. I used JWT authentication as well.

I want to retrieve data from the database for a particular user who logs in using the Login API in DRF. My intention is to interact with the database but **the problem is that I have two models in my serializer with a One-To-One relationship and I am confused about how to move forward with this issue**. To get a clearer picture, view my code below:

**models.py:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserData(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.TextField()
```

**views.py:**

```
class RegisterAPI(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = UserDataSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            content = {
            'status': 'Thanks for registering'}
            return Response(content, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

class LoginAPI(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user_id = request.user.id
        queryset = User.objects.filter(user = request.user)
        user_serializer = UserSerializer(queryset, many = True)
        return Response(user_serializer.data)
```

**serializers.py:**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from users.models import UserData
from django.contrib.auth.models import User 

class UserDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserData
        fields = ('company', 'address')

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    info = UserDataSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password', 'info')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        p_data = validated_data['info']
        password = validated_data['password', None]  
        user = User.objects.create(**validated_data)
        if password is not None:
            user.set_password(password)
        user.save() 
        UserData.objects.create(user = user, **p_data)
        return validated_data
```

**urls.py:**

```
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from users.views import LoginAPI, RegisterAPI

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('login_api', LoginAPI, basename = 'login_api')

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include(router.urls)),  
    path('register_api/', RegisterAPI.as_view(), name = 'register_api'),
]
```

**I want to return the user's Username, Email, Company and Address within the LoginAPI. These are from both the User and Profile models.**

Example:

```
{'username' = 'Tim',
 'email' = 'tim@company.com',
 'company' = 'Riko',
 'address' = 'Kenya'}
```

However, I am not able to retrieve the records from the User model and Profile model when accessing the Login API URL.

I am getting this error:

```
AttributeError at /login_api/
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `info` on serializer `UserSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `User` instance.
Original exception text was: 'User' object has no attribute 'info'.**
```

Can anyone explain to me what went wrong?

Comment: you can try to pass source to:  info = UserDataSerializer(source='userdata')

Comment: why did you include 'userdata' to the source parameter?

Answer (score 0):

DRF serializers subclasses `Field` (`serializers.Field`), so you can use the `source` argument to refer the attribute which should be used to resolve the value of the field (`UserDataSerializer` in this case):

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    info = UserDataSerializer(source='userdata')
    #                         ^^^^ Here

    ...
```

---

The error you're getting is pretty self-explanatory. You're passsing a `User` instance to the `UserSerializer` but you have a field defined as `info`. As the `User` instance does not have such attribute, it shows the error. So you need some way to tell the serializer the value of the field, using `source` to refer an existing attribite is one way of doing that.

Comment: I have tried this, but the data is not seen in POSTMAN. Instead, I am getting this: {'Detail':'User not found', 'code': user_not_found'}

Comment: @danny_boy Please do exactly as I did and come back with what you get.

Comment: I am still getting the same result despite your suggestion :( Apart from serializers.py, is there anything wrong with my other code i.e list method in views.py?

Comment: @danny_boy Your names are all over the place. You're creating a `Profile` instance in `UserSeralizer.create`, in `UserdataSerializer.Meta.model` you've set the model as `userData` (not `UserData`).

Comment: Thank you for your corrections. I don't know why, but it still does not work. Also, when I add in the source argument, I'm not able to create a user in the Register API.

Comment: @danny_boy I think you're not proving the correct data in your question. And also I think some bits are missing.

Comment: Some bits are missing as in? It would be great if you can explain or present a small demonstration. I've been on this problem for more than 8 hours.